# How to use uiwebview to show some web page?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiwebview

How to use uiwebview to show some web  page for url request? i dont know how to do it. who can tell me how to do it?  has any opensource? thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```